# what's wrong with my insert statement? mysql java

Tags: java, sql

what's wrong with my insert method?
my table has two columns, name, and artist..and timestamp, that too 
actually, how do i pass timestamp argument to the insert statement?

```
ok.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            try {
                /*FileWriter dir = new FileWriter(nameOfSong.getText()
                        + ".txt");
                BufferedWriter buffer = new BufferedWriter(dir);
                buffer.write(nameOfSong.getText());
                buffer.newLine();
                buffer.write(artist.getText());
                buffer.newLine();
                buffer.newLine();
                buffer.write(lyrics.getText());
                buffer.close();
                */

                Statement statement = connection.createStatement();
                statement.executeUpdate("INSERT INTO lyrics1_lyrics1 VALUES(" +
                nameOfSong.getText() + ", " + artist.getText() + "");


            } catch (Exception z) {
                System.err.println("Error: " + z.getMessage());
            } 
            internalFrame.dispose();
        }
    });
)
```

Comment: You might consider changing to using a PreparedStatement to avoid the SQL injection vulnerability.

Comment: you need INSERT INTO TALBE_NAME ( [COLUMN1][, COLUMN2][, COLUMN_N] ) VALUES( [VALUE FOR COLUMN 1][, VALUE FOR COLUMN 2][, VALUE FOR COLUMN N] ); also note that strings needs to be surrounded by single quotes 'this is a string'

Comment: @DorinDuminica You don't necessarily need the column names.

Comment: @DaveNewton really? suppose you have a table "TestTable" columns "ID", "Name", "Date" and you want to insert a new record with target for "Date" only with SQL: INSERT INTO "TestTable" VALUES( '2012-01-01' ); where will the engine insert the date value, in "ID", "Name" or "Date", it's not a tricky question, but I always thought that you need to specify target columns if number of values != number of columns, and in his case "name, and artist..and timestamp" he has 3 columns.

Comment: **PLEASE, PLEASE, PLEASE** work on making questions useful for future people: If you can't it likely "isn't a real question". E.g. "what doesn't work"? At least part of this should be in the title! Well, it's obvious to many of us ;-) but take some time to include the error message/symptoms! They are also great terms to SEARCH SO with.

Comment: @DorinDuminica Yes, if you're not setting all columns, or putting them in a different order, you need the column names--hence the "necessarily" part.

Comment: @DaveNewton a OK, so I misunderstood, sorry

Answer (score 6):

Always use `PreparedStatement`.

```
 String sql="INSERT INTO lyrics1_lyrics1 VALUES (?,?)";
 PreparedStatement statement = connection.prepareStatement(sql);
 statement.setString(1,nameOfSong.getText());
 statement.setString(2,artist.getText());
 statement.executeUpdate();
 statement.close();
 connection.close();
```

Answer (score 4):

The text values need to be surrounded by single quotes (`''`).

And SQL-escaped to avoid [SQL injection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection) attacks, or the first time you have a song by [Little Bobby Tables](http://xkcd.com/327/), all your DB are belong to him.

Better yet, [use a `PreparedStatement`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jdbc/basics/prepared.html), and let the machine do work for you.

Answer (score 3):

You can use prepared statement for it

```
String query = "INSERT INTO lyrics1_lyrics1(name, artist, timestamp) values(?, ?, ?)";
PreparedStatement pstmt = conn.prepareStatement(query);
pstmt.setString(1, name); // set input parameter 2
pstmt.setString(2, artist);
pstmt.setString(3, new TimeStamp(new Date().getTime()));
```

You need to add an import statement for the TimeStap;

```
import java.sql.Timestamp;
```

or else use

```
pstmt.setString(3, new java.sql.TimeStamp(new Date().getTime()));
```

Example: [Prepared Statement Insert](http://www.java2s.com/Code/Java/Database-SQL-JDBC/InsertRecordsUsingPreparedStatement.htm).

You can find a lot of example in [java2s site](http://www.java2s.com/Code/Java/Database-SQL-JDBC/CatalogDatabase-SQL-JDBC.htm).

Comment: ok learning from a book, didn't about prepared statements, now i do..on the timestamp statement, it has error?

Comment: statement.setString(3, new TimeStamp(new Date().getTime()));

Comment: @JadJ `java.sql.Timestamp`, it needs to be imported. Consider keeping a window with the API docs open; things will go faster :)

Answer (score 2):

Change the line to:

```
statement.executeUpdate("INSERT INTO lyrics1_lyrics1 VALUES('" +
                    nameOfSong.getText() + "', '" + artist.getText() + "'");
```

Answer (score 1):

This might solve your problem:

```
statement.executeUpdate("INSERT INTO lyrics1_lyrics1 VALUES('" + nameOfSong.getText() + "', '" + artist.getText() + "')");`
```